# How to "layer" two scale adjustments in a formula?

Tags: algorithms

First: I apologize for the title, I truly don't know what the correct terms to describe my problem are. If I receive suggestions for a more appropriate title or learn some new terms I will revise it.

I am working on a formula (in Excel) that will control the volume level that is restored when a user un-pauses an audio player. Rather than restore to 100% of the previous volume I want to restore to a percentage of the previous level based on two criteria:

1. Previous volume % of max volume (zero previous volume has no effect, full volume would reduce restored volume by 20%. You can see this in the below formula as 0.2 / 120)
2. Duration paused within a 0-10 minute scale (0 minutes = 100% restore, 10 minutes = 50%)

I always want to restore volume to a minimum of 50% of the previous level and this is where my current formula is failing me. My current formula looks like this:

```
Volume = 1 - ((0.5 / 10) * pausedDuration)      -  ((0.2 / 120) * lastVolume)
             [ reduce based on pause duration ]    [ reduce by last vol. level ]
```

If pausedDuration is 10 and lastVolume is 120, Volume will be .3 (30%) which is below my 50% minimum. I understand why this happens but I don't know how to structure my formula to correct it.

If pauseDuration is 0 and lastVolume is 120, Volume will be .8 (80%). This is because the pauseDuration is having no reduction in restore levels but the volume was maxed out which reduced the restore volume by 20%. If the lastVolume had been 50 the restore level would be 0.916 (91.6%)

I don't want to simply clamp the value with a MAX() function as that will result in a flat output when the minimum is reach and I want a linear scale across the entire range. I'm starting suspect this needs to be broken up into two calculations: first the percentage from

My question: How can I have two values on their own scales combine to reduce a value by 0 - 0.5?

Update: I thought about breaking this calculation up to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve and I was able to make it work as two calculations.

[Working Google Spreadsheet for experimentation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZyqE_alilC4KU7VPoReg_hJ8L0qkolkRe1f5Nnf924Y/edit?usp=sharing) (change the two light blue cells to see the calculation)

Pseudo code/formula:

```
First calculate the pause duration adjustment (0-50%)
  adj1 = (0.5 / 10) * pausedDuration

Next calculate the additional volume level adjustment relative to the pause duration adjustment
  adj2 = (0.5 - adj1) / 0.5 * ((0.2 / 120) * lastVolume)

Finally you have the total restore offset
  volume = 1.0 - adj2
```

Now that is one convoluted and ugly calculation! Now that I have a working example I'm hoping someone can suggest an elegant way to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Vol = (0.5 + 0.5 * ( pausedDuration/10)) * lastVolume`

Notice that the thing in the large parens is always at least 0.5, so you'll always get at least 0.5*lastVolume; the thing in the large parens is also always at most 1.0, so you'll never get more than 1.0*lastVolume. (This assumes that pausedDuration is clamped at 10, of course.)

===
Now that I've seen your larger explanation, I think that your final code has all the right ingredients. The last line should be `vol = 1 - (adj1 + adj2)`, but otherwise it's OK.

Let me see if I have the facts straight:

- The "volume" goes from 0 (min) to 120 (max)
- pauseDuration goes from 0 to 10

You want to come out with a number between 0 and 1 representing a percentage, I guess, and you'll multiply it by 120 to get an actual volume.

I'd do this:

```
adj1 = lastVolume/120;    // ranges from 0 to 1
adj2 = pauseDuration/10;  // ranges from 0 to 1
```

You now want to apply adjustment 1, and if there's any room left over, apply adjustment 2. (At least that's what your code above did). That is

```
reduction = adj1 * 0.5 + (1 - adj1) * adj2 * 0.2;
volFraction = 1 - reduction;
newVolume = volFraction * lastVolume;
```

That's not quite symmetric in the reductions (i.e., the "50%" reduction affects the 20% one, but not the other way around), but it works pretty decently.

I can't really call this an answer, since it's more or less the thing you wrote, but slightly polished up. But I hope it helps regardless.

Comment: Are you missing an operator between the second 0.5 and the first set of ()? I tried assuming multiplication but the result is not what I would expect. Also looking at this, unless it's flying right over my head, I don't see how this takes into considering the 20% adjustment for last volume. From your reputation I'm thinking I'm missing something ;)

Comment: 1.  Yes, I was missing a "*"...call it "pseudocode" (or "bad pseudocode"). I've fixed it. 2. I didn't see an explanation of the "20%"; I just saw a random 0.2 and 120 in your formula, and figured they were attempts to compensate for what was going wrong with the "50%" thing. If you can enlarge your explanation with a few more instances (like "if you pause then restart instantly, so that "pausedDuration" is essentially zero, the newVolume should be XYY; if you pause 10 min, it should be PQR") then maybe I can help further.

Comment: OK, I figured that's what you meant but wanted to confirm. I understand the problem isn't clear and that's my fault. I've tried to clarify but I'm not sure if it's helped. Essentially I have two calculations that are reducing the restored volume from 100%. These calculations when both are used can't result in > 50% reduction.

Comment: I've added some more material; hope it's of some help.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the additional details and polishing. Your comment "That's not quite symmetric in the reductions" is valid and interesting, I would be very interested in a suggested alternate formula if you have anything in mind?

Comment: Nah...I thought about it a bit, and can't really come up with anything natural that treats the two reductions symmetrically...sorry.